# Two sql queries merged: mysqli_num_rows returns 0

Tags: mysql, sql

### Scenario

I've got two tables on my sql database:

*credentials*

```
uid|passcode
```

*requests*

```
reqid|req|uid
```

And I want a query that first checks if there's a user in "credentials" matching the given uid, then select their passcode and req.

### My query

```
SELECT credentials.passcode, requests.req FROM credentials, requests WHERE credentials.uid=[uid]
```

### What isn't working

If there's no matching "req" for the given uid but there's a passcode, mysqli_num_rows returns 0, while I would need it to return 1.

### My question

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: That is common mysql logic to return 0 if there is no match in credentials table. For me it sounds like it makes more sense to change your business logic, than to change the standard functionality from mysql, or why do you need to have returned 1. What would need to be the return value if there is a match?

Comment: @bdifferent I'm afraid there's been a misunderstanding. What I don't understand is when there *is* a result in credentials but there isn't none in requests and mysql returns 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `LEFT JOIN` to get output when there is no result in other(right) table

```
SELECT c.passcode, r.req
FROM credentials c
LEFT JOIN requests r ON c.uid = r.uid
WHERE c.uid=[uid];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
   SELECT credentials.passcode, requests.req FROM credentials, requests WHERE credentials.uid=requests.uid
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this won't work if there is a record in credentials but not in requests